# Dynamically create rows in react bootstrap from 1d array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an array of column names and am trying to dynamically create a table with 2 columns (name and type). "Name" will be the name of the column and "type" will be a dropdown button to select a type (to be implemented later, just want to print a button for now).

This the code I have so far, it doesn't work at all and I'm getting "Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag".

Cols example, I am loading it with the below code:

```
const [cols, setCols] = useState(null);
d3.csv('/test.csv').then(data -> setCols(data.columns));

console.log(cols);
["name", "address", "zip", "number", ...]
```

```
<ReactBootstrap.Table striped bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column</th>
      <th>Import As</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {
      cols.map((col) => (
        <td><p>{col}</p></td>
        <td><div><button>Skipped</button></div></td>
      ))
    }
  </tbody>
```

Fixed it, changes below:

```
const [cols, setCols] = useState([]);

cols.map((col) => (
    <Fragment>
        <tr>
          <td><p>{col}</p></td>
          <td><div><button>Skipped</button></div></td>
        </tr>
    </Fragment>
))
```

Comment: Can you add an example of `cols` so we know what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the contents of your returned HTML with a `Fragment` tag:

```
cols.map((col) => (
    <Fragment>
        <td><p>{col}</p></td>
        <td><div><button>Skipped</button></div></td>
    </Fragment>
))
```

Comment: After adding that, the error is gone, thanks! However, I am now getting no output for the whole App. Chrome dev tools shows that there is an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')" at the <tbody> tag containing this code.

Comment: Where is `cols` stored? In state? In props? Why are you `mapping` over the column names in the `tbody`? That should be handled in the `<thead>` element surely? Where is the data you're going to populate the `tbody` with?

Comment: Yeah it is stored in state, I have added the code on how I'm loading the csv.

Comment: you are missing a `<tr>` tag between the tbody and the tds

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

Comment: It seems like the problem you have is that the cols object is coming null so when you are tying to access the map method (cols.map) you are getting a null reference error you need to add a null check:

`{ cols && cols.map((col) ...`